# PHP cURL Upload file without processing

Tags: php, rest, curl, file-upload, tableau-api

I am trying to upload a file to a Rest API (Tableau Server Rest API) endpoint using PHP cURL.

The [file upload procedure](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm#REST/rest_api_concepts_publish.htm%3FTocPath%3DConcepts%7C_____9) exists of three steps:

1. Initiate file upload (request upload token)
2. Append file upload (upload file data)
3. Publish resource (save the file)

I was having issues with the server giving me a 500 status code on the second step. After contacting the support we figured out that the problem is most likely that the curl request seems to using the `-data` flag instead of the [`--data-binary`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary) flag which means some kind of encoding happens on the request body which should **not** be happening. This causes the server to respond with a 500 status code instead of an actual error message...

I would like to know how i can make a cURL request with the `--data-binary` flag in PHP.

Relevant sections of my current code:

```
// more settings
$curl_opts[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] = $method;
$curl_opts[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = true;
$curl_opts[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = $headers;
$curl_opts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $body;
//more settings

curl_setopt_array( $this->ch, $curl_opts );
$responseBody = curl_exec( $this->ch );
```

`$method` is "PUT", `$headers` contains an array with `Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=boundary-string` and the `$body` is constructed like this:

```
$boundary = md5(date('r', time()));

$body = "--$boundary\n";
$body .= "Content-Disposition: name='request_payload'\nContent-Type: text/xml\n\n";
$body .= "\n--$boundary\n";
$body .= "Content-Disposition: name='tableau_file'; filename='$fileName'\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\n\n";
$body .=  file_get_contents( $path );
$body .= "\n--$boundary--";
```

Where the `$boundary` is the same as the boundary-string in the content-type header.
i am aware this is a kinda/very messy way to construct my body, i am planning to use Mustache as soon as i can actually upload my files :S

(i would like to mention that this is my first post here, please be gentle...)

Comment: show how you're building `$body`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, added it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up trying to implement a "--data-binary" using the `exec` function in PHP. Before i could move to this i had to cleanup some of my request body building code. This cleanup involved moving from string building (`$body .= "this" . $that . "\n";`) to a template engine (Mustache). Somehow this change fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS can accept an array of key=value field pairs. DON'T build your own mime body.

This is all you should have, really:

```
$data = array(
    'tableau_file' => '@/path/to/file';
                       ^---tell curl this field is a file
    etc..
);

curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Does this mean curl will automatically add all the `multipart/mixed` data around the file as well? Should i write my body to `php://temp` and then upload that? or can i put all that in the array somehow?

Comment: if curl sees you're doing a file upload, it'll automatically switch to multipart/form-data. you can probably override that to multipart/mixed, though I have no idea how things will work out in that case.

Comment: Okay... then i'll try uploading the file "pure" (which i dont give a high chance of working sadly :S) and after than i can try writing the whole thing to a file and uploading that instead...
Thanks for the help!